# How to combine holder.js and lazyload.js on img tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-lazyload, holder.js

According to this [link](https://github.com/imsky/holder/issues/24), lazyload is now compliant with the holder.js script.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/zBuJV/1/). I am expecting the third image to be fading in like the others. But I cannot get it to work.

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

**HTML :**

```
<img data-src="holder.js/200x200/industrial" data-original="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/bmw_m1_hood.jpg" alt="BMW M1 Hood">
<img data-src="holder.js/200x200/industrial" data-original="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/bmw_m1_side.jpg" alt="BMW M1 Side">
<img data-src="holder.js/200x200/industrial" data-original="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/does-not-exist" alt="Viper 1">
<img data-src="holder.js/200x200/industrial" data-original="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/viper_corner.jpg" alt="Viper Corner">
<img data-src="holder.js/200x200/industrial" data-original="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/bmw_m3_gt.jpg" alt="BMW M3 GT">
<img data-src="holder.js/200x200/industrial" data-original="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/corvette_pitstop.jpg" alt="Corvette Pitstop">
```

**JS :**

```
$(function () {
    $("img").lazyload({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        effectspeed: 2000,
        skip_invisible: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the "missing" placeholder doesn't fade in is because lazyLoad's `load` event never fires on it (its image doesn't exist). You'll need to specify how many images you expect to load and fade them in manually: http://jsfiddle.net/zBuJV/2/

```
$(function () {
    var expectedImages = 5;
    var loadExpected = (function (totalImages, finishCallback) {
        var total = totalImages;
        var loaded = 0;
        return function () {
            loaded++;
            if (loaded >= total) {
                finishCallback();
            }
        }
    })(expectedImages, function () {
        $("img").fadeIn(2000);
    });

    $("img").lazyload({
        effect: "hide",
        effectspeed: 0,
        skip_invisible: false,
        load: function () {
            loadExpected();
        }
    });
});
```

lazyLoad doesn't provide an `error` event, so lazy loading missing images is not easy. If you want to lazy load when the user is scrolling, you'll need to add a scroll spy to fade in images that are known to be loaded at that scroll location as well as any other registered images (i.e. placeholders).

Comment: I did not comment on time, but thanks for your answer. It helped.